# Dynamically Populate select elements in JQuery with database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two select elements both being populated with data from a database. Depending on the first select's choice the second one will display specific options. It seems to be working but from the server-side i am getting an error that should only display on the else statement, which means both if and else statements are being executed. Here's my code:

**JS:**

```
// Attach an event listener to the submit button
select_inst.addEventListener('change', () => {
  // Get the selected value from the select element
  const selectedValue = select_inst.value;
  console.log(selectedValue);

  // Send the selected value to the server-side script using AJAX
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', '/assets/php/get-course.php');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
    // Parse the JSON response
    const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    
    // Get the second select element
    const select_course = document.getElementById('select-courses');

    // Remove all existing options from the select element
    select_course.innerHTML = '';

    // Loop through the options and create a new option element for each one
    for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
      const option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = response[i].value;
      option.text = response[i].text;
      select_course.appendChild(option);
    }
  };
  xhr.send(`institution=${selectedValue}`);
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
// var_dump($_POST);

// Database connection settings
$host = 'host';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$database = 'database_name';

// Connect to the database
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);

mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8mb4");

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$institution = '';

// Check if the institution value is set
if (isset($_POST['institution'])) {

  $institution = $_POST['institution'];
  // var_dump($institution);

  // Prepare a SQL statement to retrieve data from the specified column
  $sql = "SELECT Nome_Curso FROM listed_courses WHERE Nome_Instituicao = '$institution'";

  // Query the database to retrieve data from the specified column
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  $options = [];

  // Loop through the result set and add each option value to the array
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $options[] = array(
      'value' => $row['Nome_Curso'],
      'text' => $row['Nome_Curso']
    );
  }

  // Convert the array to a JSON string and send it as the response
  echo json_encode($options);
} else {
  // Return an error message if the institution value is not set
  echo "Error: Institution value is not set.";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Everytime I select an option from the first select element this error 'Error: Institution value is not set.' shows up, which is told to execute on the else statement

Comment: Just to clarify, that is the error that shows up in your error console for **console.log(xhr.responseText);**?

Comment: @imvain2 no, it’s the one on the php file for the else statement: echo "Error: Institution value is not set."

Comment: So you are just opening the PHP in your browser's address bar?

Comment: @code_dev check value is actually posting to get-cource.php file. Debug that or in your current console.log is that printing the value?

Comment: @imvain2 On the console log after choosing an option on the first select it appears xhr finished loading: POST “path/to/get-course.php” I click on it and it opens the php file. So yeah pretty much I am opening the file on the browser

Comment: @MaheshThorat yes the value of the response is being printed on the console log

Comment: When you click the link to open it in the browser, it isn't posting anything at that point. I would ignore that as its not an actual problem.

Comment: @imvain2 i am ok with not seeing anything when I open it on the browser because at the end it works. my concern is the fact that is executing both if(isset ...) and else statements.

Comment: With your code above you're open to SQL injections like a swiss cheese. Please stop whatever you're doing and go learn about prepared statements. https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: @code_dev in your **console.log(xhr.responseText);?** it is executing both if/else or are you saying in console.log you are seeing the proper IF response, but when you click on the link and open in your browser it is running the else? If that is the case, that is normal behavior. In your console, it is running your IF because you are posting to it, but when you click the link to open in your browser it isn't posting so its running your else. This isn't a problem and is expected.

Comment: @imvain2 what I am telling is both if and else statements are being executed because the options are showing up on the select element and the error message is being displayed when I open the php file, message that is inside the else statement on the php code

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yeah I was told that, I am just trying to fix this issue before heading to the security part

Comment: @code_dev that IS the expected process. If you don't want to see the else statement don't click on the link to open it in a new tab. By clicking the link to open it in a new tab, that ISN'T reposting the same data. It is running the PHP file again, without anything posting to it.